# Connection between "But the consequences of [...]" and "someone cannot do [...]"

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-meaning

The text is quoted from a letter written by Thomas Jefferson to James Madison in 1785. ([source](http://press-pubs.uchicago.edu/founders/documents/v1ch15s32.html))

> I am conscious that an equal division of property is impractable. **But
>   the consequences of this enormous inequality producing so much misery
>   to the bulk of mankind, legislators cannot invent too many devices for
>   subdividing property**, only taking care to let their subdivisions go
>   hand in hand with the natural affections of the human mind.

I'm not quite sure how "`But the consequences of [...]`" and "`legislators cannot invent [...]`" are connected together using a comma.

Is it correct that this sentence means "`Because of the consequences of [...], legislators cannot invent [...]`"?

Thanks :)

Comment: That is correct. The passage is merely archaic, as might more easily be seen by dropping *But the consequences of* and starting the sentence at *This enormous…*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's right. I'd translate to:

> Because enormous inequality produces widespread misery, legislators
>   should always look for new ways to subdivide property.